# Host Multi domains on Linux ( Ubuntu ) from Linode.com provider with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I have a Ubuntu from Linode.com. I'm trying to host multi website ( domains, each will listen to different ports ). Here is what I did:
In file mysite.com.conf:

```
Listen *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In file ports.conf

```
Listen *81
```

Then run command in terminal:

```
sudo a2ensite mysite.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then I setup DNS Manager for domain mysite.com
But when I visit mysite.com from browser, it always listen to port 80. So when I setup multiply Virtual Host file as above, for different domains, All of them just route to port 80. 
Do  you know which step I missed and how to tell Apache to redistribute to different port according to incoming domains name ? 
I followed tutorial [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: This is not how port selection works. I doubt you _really_ want to use different ports. You'd have to use URLs like https : //www.mysite.com:81/ to reach such http server. That hardly is desirable. Instead you want to use "name based virtual hosts", where all hosts listen _on the same port number_. Take a look at the documentation of the apache http server. That is the common technology these days to host multiple hostnames / domains.

Comment: I read tutorial here on Apache Site: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html   If I have to put the port after domains name then I can achieve that without doing anything with Apache.

Comment: What do you mean by "then I can achieve that without doing anything with Apache"? You certainly _do_ use the apache http server and you certainly _do_ have to configure it - regardless of whether you use name or port based virtual hosts.

Comment: You don't have to install Apache and don't have to configure anything If You put the port after domain name like: mysite.com:8080 or mysite.com:9090. You don't need Apache for this to work. If you open the port 8080 by ufw on Ubuntu then mysite.com:8080 works without needing Apache.

Comment: Um, sorry, no. You definitely do need an http server. How else do you want to serve http?You certainly can use another http server software, it does not have to be the apache implementation. But you need _some_.

Comment: If you build a java web app, pack  in .jar file. Then upload on your Ubuntu server.   In terminal, run:   java -jar app.jar   Then you can put port after the domain name you set for you app.jar, let say 8080. After that, visit the site by: mysite.com:8080. No Apache or any other Ngnix or any server needed.

Comment: Of course, then you implemented your own http server, that's all. Which you obviously also can do when using port 80, so without the need to specify a port number in the URL. I don't see what that has to do with virtual hosting and why you tagged this question with `apache` then...

Comment: Back to your original question and my first comment: I explained that _if_ you use _port based virtual hosts_ (as you do in your example), then you _do_ have to specify a port number in the URL. How else should the browser know which port to connect to? If you use _name based virtual hosts_, then multiple domains / hostnames can be served using a single port number (so probably the standard http port 80), so that you do _not_ have to specify that port in the URL.

Comment: As questioner, I'm expecting guidance, suggestion. You can realize the purpose of this  question is: How to distribute request based on incoming domains so that one Ubuntu server can support multiple websites. Putting port after domain name is something for dev, not for users. If you know any software solving this problem ( for sure there is ) then please suggest. I'm trying Docker now. Hope it works

Comment: I actually explained _twice_ to you how to achieve what you ask.

Comment: Again I suggest that you take a look into the documentation of the apache http server. It is of great quality and comes with good examples. Here is the section about "name based virtual hosting" which is what you want to use: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 0):

Tran

I have this in my configuration and hope it will help you.

But first of all you will need to **disable** the **000-default.conf** by doing this

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Then after add the ports you want apache to listen to
for example my apache listens to the following ports
80,8080,1000 and port 8000 in my configuration file **ports.conf**

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Then your **mysite.com.conf** should look something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/mysite.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Aftre doing all that work, write the following commands

```
sudo a2ensite mysite.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then try accessing your site like this

```
mysite.com
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: What I want is just visit: mysite.com and it will automatically look for the port of that domain and reroute to it.  mysite.com:8080 is not the right choice for regular users.

Comment: have you tried visting your site like this mysite.com without adding 8080 and didnt work

Comment: If I didn't put the port 8080 after domain then it will automatically reroute to port 80.

Comment: Please checkout my edited content coz it maybe of some help

Comment: Hey V.Tran, Did my answer help